# Evaluating the derivative of $f(x)=x^2\sin^2\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$ gives $0$, but the graph of $f'(x)$ isn't defined at $x=0$. Why?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am new to calculus. I am having an issue in this problem. If we have a function $$f(x)=x^2 \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ If I try to differentiate it and try to find its value at $x=0$ by using first principle of differentiation, I get
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$
which on simplification gives $f'(0)=0$. But if I see the graph of its derivative, I see $f'(x)$ does not have any defined value at $x=0$. Why is it so? 
Edit- The value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is $0$

Comment: Your question is missing something— What is the value of $f$ at $x=0$? I assume it's $0$ but as it stands, the definition of $f$ you provide is not defined when $x=0$ which is exactly why you're seeing $f'$ is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: ohh yes, i forgot to mention it

Comment: Well if $f(0)=0$ then indeed $f'(0)$ exists or is defined at $x=0$ and as you calculated, $f'(0)$ is $0$. You *need* to add that information in your graphing tool as well. Otherwise it will show you that $f'$ is not defined at $x=0$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes. my doubt is clear now

Comment: Observe that $\sin^2(\text{whatever})$ is a red herring.  Take any bounded function $g$ defined on interval containing $0$. Then $x^2g(x)$ is differentiable in $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is a nice and strange function.

It is indeed differentiable at $0$ and its derivative is equal to zero at that point as you proved it. However, the limit at the origin of the derivative doesn't exist.

**Both things are not incompatible though.**

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong,. f'(x) is not continuous at x=0 but f(x) is differentiable at x=0 because left hand derivative and right hand derivative are are equal. Also, if I m correct, please tell me how can I prove that LHL and RHL of f'(x) are not same at x=0

Comment: In fact, LHS and RHS side of $f^\prime$ doesn't even exist. They oscillate between $-1$ and $1$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

What the graph (shown below) suggests is that $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$ (and, yes, $f'$ *is* discontinuous at $0$). That, however, does not prevent $f$ from being differentiable at $0$.

[image]